# iMacros script not looping correctly when added into a JS script

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox-addon, imacros

I have an iMacros script that loops correctly when run in isolation - reading through all rows of the input table - BUT does not loop at all when included in my JS script.

Here is iMacros script that works independently when I set the "Repeat Macro" 'Max:' variable

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE Org_Acc_DK.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 4
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=http://SOME SITE HERE (replaced the name to protect the guilty)
WAIT Seconds=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:MainContent_btnNewAcct
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:MainContent_ucAddOrganisationAccount_ddOrgList CONTENT={{!COL1}}
WAIT Seconds=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:MainContent_ucAddOrganisationAccount_txtOAAccount CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:MainContent_ucAddOrganisationAccount_ddlOACountry CONTENT=$*{{!COL3}}*
WAIT Seconds=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:MainContent_ucAddOrganisationAccount_ddOALessor CONTENT=$*{{!COL4}}*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:btnOASave
WAIT Seconds=3
```

When I added that script to the following JS script - it only runs once then goes back to the JS script and completes. 
Now I realize it is because I did not set the "Repeat Macro" to the number of rows. BUT what do I need to add to the JAVA script to just set the repeat rows ONLY for this particular script and not those before or after it?

```
var i, retcode;
var report;
var macrolist = new Array();


macrolist.push("Create Account/0 Login");
macrolist.push("Create Account/01 Create Organisation And Account.iim");
macrolist.push("Create Account - DK Loop.iim");



iimDisplay("Start Self Test");

report  =  "Self-Test Report\n\n";

for (i = 0; i < macrolist.length; i++) {
iimDisplay("Step "+(i+1)+" of "+macrolist.length + "\nMacro: "+macrolist[i]);
retcode = iimPlay(macrolist[i]);
report += macrolist[i];
if (retcode < 0) {
    report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
} else {
    report += ": OK";

    s = iimGetLastExtract(1);
    if ( s != "" )  report += ", Extract: "+s;
}
report += "\n";
}
iimDisplay("Test complete");

alert ( report );
```

Thanks in advance,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

A very helpful friend of mine developed a Java script to do exactly what I needed. The external calls to the CSV files to get the data will loop through the sheets until the last record is found using this script.

It was so good I felt it necessary to share it with others that may end up in a similar situation as me.

The only change you really need to make to the iMacros script is to add "POSVAL" to the "SET !LOOP" command as follows:

```
SET !LOOP {{POSVAL}}
```

Firstly all referenced data sources need to be expressed and identify which macro they are being used by.

```
var i, retcode, report;
var macro2_file="Org_Acc_info.csv";
var macro3_file="Testfile1.csv";
var macro4_file="Testfile2.csv";
var macro5_file="Details_Tab.csv";
```

A single log-on script is run before the looping scripts are run.

```
retcode = iimPlay("Create Account/0 Login");
report = "";
if (retcode < 0) report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
```

Then the header reference code for the looping routines

```
var lines_in_file;
```

Then the individual files I want to loop starting with macro2

```
 lines_in_file = count_rows(get_data_folder()+"\\", macro2_file);

for (i=2; i<=lines_in_file ; i++)
{
  retcode = iimSet("POSVAL",  i);
  retcode = iimPlay("Create Account/01 Create Organisation And Account.iim");
  if (retcode < 0) report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
}
```

Then macro3

```
lines_in_file = count_rows(get_data_folder()+"\\", macro3_file);

for (i=2; i<=lines_in_file ; i++)
{
  retcode = iimSet("POSVAL",  i);
  retcode = iimPlay("Create Account - DK Loop - VBS.iim");
  if (retcode < 0) report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
}
```

Then macro4

```
lines_in_file = count_rows(get_data_folder()+"\\", macro4_file);

for (i=2; i<=lines_in_file ; i++)
{
  retcode = iimSet("POSVAL",  i);
  retcode = iimPlay("Create Account/2 Create Account Address.iim");
  if (retcode < 0) report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
}
```

Then macro5

```
lines_in_file = count_rows(get_data_folder()+"\\", macro5_file);

for (i=2; i<=lines_in_file ; i++)
{
  retcode = iimSet("POSVAL",  i);
  retcode = iimPlay("Create Account/4 Edit Account Details.iim");
  if (retcode < 0) report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
}
```

Then the main body of the looping code

```
function get_data_folder()
{
  var code;
  code =  "CODE:";
  code +=  "SET !extract {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}" + "\n";
  iimPlay(code);
  return iimGetLastExtract(0);
}


function count_rows(datasource,csv_file_name)
{
  // COUNT THE NUMBERS OF NON-BLANK ROWS IN CSV FOR LOOP
  const CRLF = "\r\n";
  const LF = "\n";

  var lines = new Array();

  var file_i = imns.FIO.openNode(datasource+csv_file_name);
  var text = imns.FIO.readTextFile(file_i); // Read file into one string

  // Determine end-of-line marker
  var eol = (text.indexOf(CRLF) == -1) ? LF : CRLF;

  // Split into lines (number of lines) NUMBER OF LINES IN CSV
  lines = text.split(eol);
  var count=0;
  for(var i=0;i< lines.length; i++){
    if (lines[i]!="") count++;
  }
// FINISH COUNTING count= NUmber of LInes
return count;
}
```